# Compare two array and find match value and print

Tags: php, arrays, curl, foreach

I have two arrays named `$data` and `$new_el`, and two `foreach` loops for two arrays. Below is my code.

I want to compare both array its 0 index variable because both array having same name variable its 0 index.i give some condition for variable value in $data array.like if $data array 0 index variable is 0 then it store "CJ",if variable length is 1,2 or 3 then it assign 01,02,03 etc.and if variable value is 11,12 means two digit store same as come from server. and the compare both array and if both array 0 index value is match then print all the value of 1,2,3,etc index.

I tried much but I could not find any solution. Please help as soon as possible.

```
function curlUsingGet($url, $data)
{
  if(empty($url) OR empty($data))
  {
    return 'Error: invalid Url or Data';
  }

  $fields_string = '';
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
  }
  rtrim($fields_string,'&');

  $urlStringData = $url.'?'.$fields_string;
  $_SESSION['urlStringData'] = $urlStringData;
  $cookie = "cookie.txt";
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
    Windows NT 6.1)");          
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urlStringData);

  $return = curl_exec($ch);
  $arrele = explode('|',$return);

  foreach ($arrele as $val) {
    $num = 0;

    $new_el = explode('~',$val);
    $crt = $new_el[0];
    if ($crt == '0') {
      echo $crt = "CJ";
    } elseif (strlen($crt) == 1) {
      echo $crt = sprintf($num,$crt);
    } else {
      echo $crt;
    }
  } 
  $_SESSION['court'];
  $courtone = explode(',', $_SESSION['court']);
  $len = count($courtone);
  if ($len < 2) {
    echo "Invalid data from server";
  }
  $courtstring = $courtone[0];
  $_SESSION['courtnewdate'] = $courtone[1];


  $courtnew = explode('~',$courtstring);
  foreach ($courtnew as $val) {
    $data = explode('@@',$val);
    $data[0];
  }

  curl_close($ch);
}

$data = array('u' => $_SESSION['councel']);
echo curlUsingGet('http://"url":8080/causelist/CauseListData', $data);
```

Comment: As I see it, this question has little to do with curl, foreach, PHP or arrays. You are just asking us to debug a piece of obfuscated code. I very doubt the answer would help anybody but you, so I'll pass on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This may help , lets say I need to find match between two array $a and $b, the array_intersect() function can be used for this

```
$matches  = array_intersect($a,$b);
```

The above will find the the common element which are in $a as well as in $b

```
$array1 = array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

print_r(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
```

The above will output as

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 6 )
```

Comment: i want matched  element not different.

Answer (score -1):

Question is long and not easy to understand.
you can compare array with function array_diff . Please check link.
https://www.php.net/array_diff